# move matrix 3x3 array right and upward

Tags: javascript

I have create the matrix 3x3 from 1-9

```
var data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ];

var i = 0;
for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
  document.write('<br>');
  for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    document.write(data[i++]);
    document.write('&nbsp');
  }
}
```

And the result will be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

How to make it possible to move the matrix right and then upward like this

```
3 1 2    6 4 5
6 4 5    9 7 8
9 7 8    3 1 2
```

I know thing like splice or etc but I got confuse on how to implement it :(
Thank you! :)

Comment: is it 312 or 321,645,987

Comment: so it will move rightward from 1 2 3 to 3 1 2 all elements

Comment: sounds like homework

Comment: unfortunately no :p it's just a test xD

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by transcribing the elements of the old matrix into a new matrix by the order they need to be to accomplish the translation.

move-right:

```
int i = 0;
for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
    for (var c = 1; c < 3+1; c++) {
        newData[i++] = data[3*r+c%3];
    }
}
```

move-up:

```
int i = 0;
for (var r = 1; r < 3+1; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        newData[i++] = data[3*(r%3)+c];
    }
}
```

The entire trick is being performed by the expression in the data index, using a modulo to count from 1 and wrap around to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the new index in a single loop.

```js
var data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    result[(i % 3 + 1) % 3 + ((Math.floor(i /3) + 2) % 3) * 3] = a;
});

console.log(result);
```